# Transferring my dynamic value from response data to excel file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to actually transfer my dynamic value from the response data to Excel file in Jmeter... can anyone plz let me know the clear process for it ?
I used beanshell post processor but dint got the expected output...

Comment: can you add the sample code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache POI - Java API To Access Microsoft Excel Format Files](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/), this way you will be able to create, read and update Excel files from Beanshell code. The easiest way to add binary documents formats support to JMeter is using [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/), given you have [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you will be able to view Excel files contents using [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and use Apache POI API to manipulate Excel files.

Minimal working code for creating an Excel file and adding to it JMeter variable value looks like:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(vars.get("your_variable"));
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("FileCreatedByJMeter.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

References:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-extract-data-files-jmeter)